# Xcode 11 Build System Bugged?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, xcode11

I am using `Xcode 11 GM` with macOS `Mojave 10.14.6`. I have been experiencing problems with my app's build. What I mean is that the first time I compile an app on my iPhone, its okay but then if I make changes to the code and compile again: it doesn't show those changes. But when I do it on the simulator the changes do show. In order to see the changes on my phone, I have to `uninstall` and `reinstall` the app. I have also been looking for known issues on apple's website:
[Known Bugs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes?preferredLanguage=occ).

But I cannot seem to find a specific bug for what I am experiencing? My iPhone is the XR model version 13.1.2.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you delete DerivedData?

Comment: Yes i did, still the same.

Comment: Clean build folder?

Comment: Yes, also tried cmd shift k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and what did it for me was to chose the **Legacy build system** instead of the New build system in the Workspace settings:

1. Click on "File" in Xcode top menu
2. Click on "Workspace settings"
3. Chose the **Legacy build system** for the Build system setting

I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you! I found a even better solution that doesn't involves switching to the legacy build system. I opened the workspace settings and on the shared settings it showed the "new system" but in the pre user settings it showed "use share setting" so i changed that value to match the "new system" and now it works correctly. If. you want to edit your answer to another solution.